# Is fuel balancing done automatically?

Tags: commercial-aviation, pilots, airbus

Is the balacing of the fuel in the wings of an aircraft like A320 done automatically or does it have to be done manually by the pilot. If it is done manually does the pilot eyeball the balancing ?

Answer (score 3):

The A320 has an auto mode that will do the following:

- Center tank will empty first.
- The inner wing tanks will empty until they reach 750 kg in each.
- The outer tank transfer valves will open and remain open allowing fuel to flow to the inner tanks.
- The center tank pump will stop 5 minutes after low level is reached and remain stopped until the inner wing tank reaches the underfill sensor (approx. 500 kg) at which point it will restart.

The center tank pumps can be switched to manual mode.
The wing tanks can be turned off manually.
The cross feed valve is also operated manually.

source: A320 FCOM

Answer (score 2):

During refueling, it is generally automatic. The fuel handler will just set the amount of fuel to pump in and the pipes will distribute it to the tanks as appropriate.

In flight, there is a schedule which tanks are used first, which is automatic (see TomMcW's answer), but this is not balancing—the left wing tanks only feed engines on the left wing and the right wing tanks only feed engines on the right wing.

If an imbalance appears, meaning the amount of fuel in the left and right wing tanks is significantly different, a warning is generated. There is a cross-feed valve that the pilots can open to let all engines use the fuller tank, but it is not automatic, because unless one engine was shut down in flight (which in twins calls for landing as soon as possible anyway), it usually means the fuel is leaking somewhere and leaving the cross-feed valve open would lead to repeating of the incident of [Air Transat flight 236](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Transat_Flight_236).

Answer (score 0):

On multi-engine jets there is not so much of a need to balance fuel as there is on single-piston aircraft.

1. The aircraft tends to fly in balance all the time, so there is no differential feed of fuel.
2. All the engines burn fuel at the same rate, so there is no cause fo a Fuel Imbalance. In fact, a Fuel Imbalance is usually seen as the first symptom of a Fuel leak.